# How to remove filtered items from collection view in swift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am developing an application in swift where you have the possibility to filter the data displayed in the UICollectionView. After the data is filtered, collection view should update, so only items which fit the filter will be visible(eg. price is more than 30$). I can't update the collection view, I've tried literally everything...(reloadData(), deleteItems(at: IndexPath), batch, etc...) Here is the code for collection view functions:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dogsSort.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 150)
}
internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedDog = dogsSort[indexPath.row]
    
    print("selected dog " + selectedDog.name)
    
    let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemVC") as! ItemViewController
    vc.dog = selectedDog
    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    
   /*storageWizard.getImage(path: "/dogs/" + dogsSort[indexPath.row].id + "/image.png",         imageCompletionHandler: { (image) -> Void in
        cell.imageView.image = image
        self.dogsSort[indexPath.row].image = image
            
        return
    })*/
    print(indexPath.row)
    
    if dogsSort.count > indexPath.row {
        cell.btnPrice.setTitle("Get for " +  String.init(self.dogsSort[indexPath.row].price) + "$", for: .normal)
        cell.labelView.text = self.dogsSort[indexPath.row].name
        cell.CityView.text = self.dogsSort[indexPath.row].description
        cell.breedView.text = self.dogsSort[indexPath.row].breed
        cell.ageView.text = self.dogsSort[indexPath.row].age
        cell.weightView.text = self.dogsSort[indexPath.row].weight
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

And code which I am using currently, dummy code just to test the functionality, but it is not working...

```
dogsSort.remove(at: 0)
collectionView.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)])
collectionView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Define "not working". Also, according to your code, you shouldn't need  `dogsSort.count > indexPath.row`. Where is called your "dummy code" exactly?

Comment: is dogSort the filtered array or the original one?

Comment: dogSort is original array. Then I do something like
dogsSort = dogsSort.filter { dog in
     return dog.price > 50
}

Comment: @Larme 
Not working - not refreshing collection view. Not removing data which is filtered.
I am calling the dummy code on button "filter" click.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question this is what you have to do:

- get your main array of dogs;
- filter it:

```swift
filtered = dogsArray.filter({ $0.price > 30 })
```

- If you want to filter the items based on a certain property, set again:

```swift
filtered = dogsArray.filter({$0.name == "something"})
```

In your `CollectionView`'s delegate and data source methods you need to work with the filtered array, ie. (for the number of items in row):

```swift
filtered.count
```

Comment: I've done all of that. Problem is I can't make my collection view refresh data. I write my array elements after filtering, everything is okay. Also, for collection view number of elements I am using the proper array length(length of filtered array). However, it is not removing filtered data.